# Use page Title in Gutenberg custom banner block

Tags: javascript, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I have created a custom banner image block for Gutenberg, which works great, but
I want to know if it is possible to use the page title as the current banner text 
placeholder until it has been edited?

[image]

My Edit function is

```
 return [
            el('div', {className:'header-banner'},
                el(
                    element.Fragment,
                    null,
                    controls,
                    el( "div",{
                        className: 'banner-image',
                        style: { backgroundImage: 'url('+attributes.mediaURL+')' }
                    },
                    attributes.title || isSelected ?  el(RichText, {
                            key: 'editable',
                            tagName: "h1",
                            className: "banner-title",
                            //Can i add the page title in here if it is avaiable??
                            //placeholder: i18n.__('Write title…'),
                            value: attributes.title,
                            onChange: function onChange(value) {
                                return props.setAttributes({ title: value });
                            },
                            inlineToolbar: true
                        }) : null 

                    )
                )
            )//header-banner
        ];
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Gutenberg stores the current editor state using [wp.data](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/tree/master/packages/data), which is an abstraction over Redux. To get the title (or [100+ other values](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/master/packages/editor/src/store/selectors.js)), we need to query the `core/editor` data store. Gutenberg makes it simple to retrieve post attributes with [getEditedPostAttribute](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/data/data-core-editor/#getEditedPostAttribute).

Once we know where to look, getting the title is simple:

```js
const { select } = wp.data;
const title = select("core/editor").getEditedPostAttribute( 'title' );
```

That works, but it's not responsive. When the post title changes, `title` won't reflect the new value. That's kind of a let down.

To reflect changes to the editor title, we need to listen for changes to the `core/editor` data store. There are a few ways to do this.

One solution is to define a simple change handler function and subscribe it to data store updates:

```js
const { select } = wp.data;

function logTitle() {
  const title = select("core/editor").getEditedPostAttribute( 'title' );
  console.log("Editor Title:", title);
}
subscribe(logTitle);
```

That will fire when *any* `wp.data` store value is updated -- which happens a lot.

What seems to be the Gutenberg-sanctioned way of including data-store values is to use a higher-order component to include the value directly:

```js
const GetTitle = props => <div>{props.title}</div>;

const selectTitle = withSelect(select => ({
  title: select("core/editor").getEditedPostAttribute( 'title' )
}));
const PostTitle = selectTitle(GetTitle);
```

Then in the block's output, include a `<PostTitle />` jsx tag. That's a lot cleaner than nested callbacks or another change handler.

Higher-order components can be difficult to follow. The short explanation is that they wrap a existing component, generate some data, then return a copy of the component with the new data passed as props. This separates logic from presentation and helps with maintainability.

`GetTitle` is simple enough, it's just a small component that takes in a `props` object with a title key and spits out some html.

`withSelect` is a function constructor or decorator. It accepts a function argument, and returns a new function which expects a component. Normally the returned function is invoked immediately (sort of an [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression)) but I stored it in the `selectTitle` variable for clarity. The new function generates an object containing the title, this object will be passed as props to any components passed to `withSelect`. Through some magic this will be called whenever the data store is updated.

In the end, `PostTitle` contains the function result of `selectTitle` which is a component pre-populated with the the generated props. This component can then be placed into our markup using a `<PostTitle />` tag. Whenever the editor data-store is updated, the higher-level component will reflect the new data.

Comment: Thank you very much for this, it works great. Really good explanation as well :)

Comment: Can you then use PostTitle to update an attribute? as i can get it to work in the editor, but it doesn't seem to update the frontend content

Comment: the `getDocumentTitle` selector was deprecated and has been removed. https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/pull/9623

Comment: @joemaller use `getEditedPostAttribute( 'title' )` instead

Answer (score 2):

@joemaller thanks for the helpful response.

Here's an example that demonstrates using `withSelect()` to wrap a component defined via the `edit` property of the block configuration object passed to `registerBlockType()`.

The component is passed the `title` via props.

If the user edits the post/page title, the component is re-rendered with the new title because its props will have changed. This enables it to update in "real time".

```
import { withSelect } from '@wordpress/data'
```

...

```
edit: withSelect(
  ( select ) => {
    return {
      title: select( 'core/editor' ).getEditedPostAttribute( 'title' ),
    }
  } )( props => {
    return (
      <div>{ props.title }</div>
    )
} ),
```